# I would be interested in writing (blank) Community Blog articles!

Tags: discussion

Please upvote this post if you are interested in WRITING content for a Community Blog. This would require at a minimum a commitment to write articles at least once every 2 weeks.

Please upvote individual answers if that is the content that you would be most interested in writing. Feel free to add your own answers.

Answer (score 3):

Best of Board and Card Games - Take the most thought provoking and/or popular Q&A and transform the best few answers into blog posts. For example, a strategy question that results in separate strategies for an answer spread across 4 good answers could have all the 4 answers blended into a single blog post.

NOTE: It would be fairly easy to write posts for this blog given that it's just a matter of rearranging and lightly editing already high quality material.

Answer (score 1):

Session Reports - A weekly or bi-weekly report about how a game turned out. Perhaps with pictures or video of the game play to help people follow it. Either described from the point of view of a all knowing being, or from the perspective of a single player.

Answer (score 1):

Product Review - If you suffer from the disease of the cult of the new, you might want to have access to product reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Game Design - This might just be wishful thinking, but I hope there are enough game designer enthusiasts that are willing to share their thought process in designing a game.

Answer (score 0):

In-Depth Strategy - A deep analysis of strategy for a particular game.

Answer (score 0):

Game Theory/Game Tech - Discussions about game mechanics, or general game theory concepts.